# Iterator taking a Delegate instead of a Predicate

Tags: .net, predicate, func

I know that I can define a predicate:

```
Dim _predicate As New Func(Of T, Boolean)(Function(e)e.Foo= "Value")
```

and pass it to a LINQ method:

```
Dim _x as String = enumerable.First(predicate).Foo
```

I wanted to abstract out the "Value" string, so I created:

```
Dim _delegate As New Func(Of T, String, Boolean)(Function(e, s)e.Foo= s)
```

How can I pass this delegate to a LINQ function, passing the string parameter but still letting it assume that the T parameter is the iterator item each time?

I guess there isn't an overload available that takes such a delegate, but I don't really want to have to write my own overloads for all of the LINQ methods...

I guess what I want is an inline way to convert a Delegate to a Predicate, providing the value that replaces that extra parameter.

Comment: You need to capture `s` within a `New Func(Of T, Boolean)` delegate, not pass it to the delegate

Comment: @vc74 That's fine if the delegate is defined in the same method as `s`, say; but if I wanted to define `_delegate` at a class-level then use it in various functions, I don't want to have to set another class-level variable just for this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not a VB guy but I'm sure my code can easily be translated:

```
class ValueFilter<T>
  where T : IFooThing
{
  public ValueFilter(string value)
  {
    _value = value;
  }
  private readonly string _value;

  public IsMatch(T item) => (item.Foo == _value);
}
```

and then

```
var filter = new ValueFilter("A value");

IEnumerable<Foo> collection = ...
collection.First(filter.IsMatch);
```

(assuming `IFooThing` has a `public string Foo { get; }` property